# SQL Server Remove JSON Node Using Regex

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have database table, in a column i have JSON data, in which data was wrongly updated. I know the pattern to remove incorrect node from JSON string.

I am trying to create regex expression to remove node which has `"A":"99f7cd78-54c3-40cb-bde4-21f1b826ad86"`.

Below is JSON string in data column:

`[{"A":"957d43b6-07ce-41b4-b7b8-a6098ca08bba","RN":0,"N":"ABC 1%","R":10.00,"T":"b57d51ef-5538-4725-82eb-0f2fad4f1b82"},{"A":"99f7cd78-54c3-40cb-bde4-21f1b826ad86","RN":0,"N":"ABC 1%","R":10.00,"T":"294ac06a-1cd1-4961-8298-6e3b63ebd979"}]`

So output string should be : 
`[{"A":"957d43b6-07ce-41b4-b7b8-a6098ca08bba","RN":0,"N":"ABC 1%","R":10.00,"T":"b57d51ef-5538-4725-82eb-0f2fad4f1b82"}]`

Can someone guide me what regex i need to use in `SQL Server`?

I am new to regex.

I tried below regex:

`\s*\,\{\"A\":\"99f7cd78-54c3-40cb-bde4-21f1b826ad86\".+?}`

I am not sure how to use this regex to remove JSON properties.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with SQL Server 2016 you may use built-in JSON support, but you can't remove JSON items from JSON array using regex. One possible approach in this case is to parse the JSON using `OPENJSON` and get content as table, filter the table with the appropriate `WHERE` clause and format table rows as JSON using `FOR JSON`:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (JsonColumn varchar(1000))
INSERT INTO Data (JsonColumn)
VALUES ('[
   {"A":"957d43b6-07ce-41b4-b7b8-a6098ca08bba","RN":0,"N":"ABC 1%","R":10.00,"T":"b57d51ef-5538-4725-82eb-0f2fad4f1b82"},
   {"A":"99f7cd78-54c3-40cb-bde4-21f1b826ad86","RN":0,"N":"ABC 1%","R":10.00,"T":"294ac06a-1cd1-4961-8298-6e3b63ebd979"}
]')
```

Statement:

```
UPDATE Data
SET JsonColumn = (
   SELECT *
   FROM OPENJSON(JsonColumn) WITH (
      A varchar(50) '$.A',
      RN int '$.RN',
      N varchar(10) '$.N',
      R numeric(5, 2) '$.R',
      T varchar(50) '$.T'
   )
   WHERE A <> '99f7cd78-54c3-40cb-bde4-21f1b826ad86'
   FOR JSON PATH
)
```

Result:

```
JsonColumn
[{"A":"957d43b6-07ce-41b4-b7b8-a6098ca08bba","RN":0,"N":"ABC 1%","R":10.00,"T":"b57d51ef-5538-4725-82eb-0f2fad4f1b82"}]
```